# Rebase branch created from another branch

Tags: git

I currently have repository that looks like the following graph in terms of branches and commit.

```
o -- o                            (development)
      \
       o -- o -- o                (topicA)
                  \
                   o -- o -- o    (topicB)
```

However I'd like to rebase topicB onto the same commit topicA is based off without bringing along the changes topicB inherits from topicA so it would look like the following:

```
o -- o                            (development)
     |\
     | o -- o -- o                (topicA)
      \           
       o -- o -- o                (topicB)
```

How would I go about doing this? I tried the command:

```
git rebase --onto development topicA topicB
```

But this just seems to reset the branch to the desired commit without bringing along topicB's changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please may you show which commits the branches point to?

Comment: That rebase should do it. Can you show us the relevant part of `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` before and after the rebase?

Comment: You need to be on topicB when you give the rebase command.

Comment: @matt Yep, I though I was on the correct branch, but I was in fact not. This fixed it.

Comment: Yay! I know, the syntax is confusing.

Comment: @matt It's even more so when you usually rely on Gitkraken to do all your git work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly mistake, I wasn't checked out onto the correct branch. Also in me trying to type the command I made the error a few times to swap topicA and topicB in the command:

```
git rebase --onto development topicA topicB
```

so it would look like

```
git rebase --onto development topicB topicA
```

Comment: Note that the form: `git rebase --onto <target> <upstream> <branch>` (the one you're using) starts with a `git checkout <branch>`. You remain on `<branch>` when done, too. The rest of it is just `git rebase --onto <target> <upstream>`. I try to avoid the command you're using (with the extra `<branch>` part) because it's too easy to swap the two branch names here. The onto-plus-upstream one is bad enough!

Comment: @torek Yeah that's some good advice, I tend to use Gitkraken for most of my Git stuff so my knowledge on commandline git isn't very good. Which is probably why I made this error in the first place. But I hope that someone in the future will learn from my mistake!

Comment: That's not quite right, @torek. If you specify all 3 points, git will do the checkout before the rebase. Maybe it was correct before? But  not these days (give it a try).

Comment: @eftshift0: That's what I said: it does an initial `git checkout` of the `<branch>` argument.